# Inline field initialization vs builder which is better

Tags: java, builder

I have created a class with many fields, which I'd like to initialize most of them according to some default value while set few fields according to my needs in time. I come cross two solutions for this class.Inline field initialization and builder. Any comments? I know builder patter is popular, but why not just use default inline field initialization?

```
//Inline field initialization:

class foo{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;

    public foo setA(int a){this.a = a; return this;}
    public foo setB(int b){this.b = b; return this;}
}

//use foo
foo f = new foo().setA(1).setB(2);

//builder
class bar(){
    int a;
    int b;
    bar(int a, int b){this.a = a; this.b = b}
    public static class Builder(){
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        public bar build(){
            return new bar(a, b);
        }

        public Builder a(int a){this.a = a; return this;}
        public Builder b(int b){this.b = b; return this;}
    }
}

// use
bar b = bar.Builder.build().a(1).b(2);
```

Comment: improve your question, read this [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The builder pattern is commonly used to build [_immutable objects_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builder pattern need to be considered when faced with many constructor parameters.
Constructors do not scale well with large number of optional parameters.
Refer: Item 2 in Effective Java http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2
If the count of your fields will not increase to a large number then I will prefer to go with Inline field initialization as it means writing less code which is always good.

Comment: If  the number of parameters goes too large, what can happen if I use inline field. I can call a default constructor with all the fields initialized inline. Then call few set methods before return like I did in foo class.

Comment: Too many setter calls of javabean need to be avoided during object construction since it splits the object construction in many calls. If the number of fields with default values >> the number of fields you need to modify while object construction, go for inline else for builder.

Answer (score 0):

The major advantage of using a builder pattern is that it allows you to give the parameters in any order. For example, using inline fields you should always pass `a` and `b` in that order. Using a builder, you can pass them in any order. When the number of parameters becomes too large for the constructor, builder pattern will surely help whether you are creating immutable objects or not.

Comment: My example of foo can give parameter in any order as well since I returned this object in set method. I can initialize by foo f = new foo().setA(1).setB(2); or foo f = new foo().setB(1).setA(2); Basically, the foo class is very similar to a builder class except using new instead of static constructor. I understand there are advantages of using static methods like static getInstance() instead of a constructor. Just wonder is this the only difference?